# How to build gnome-terminal from source?

Tags: gnome-terminal

This comment looks interesting. Would like to uncomment it and rebuilt and see:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/mainline/src/org.gnome.Terminal.gschema.xml#L46

autogen.sh works but there are a lot of missing packages. Is there some setup file I am missing?

Comment: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/raw/master/tools/build/gnome-shell-build-setup.sh

Comment: https://gist.github.com/elgalu/a17180c7115bc6df46db